# How to summarise out of group observations in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

I am trying to replicate [Gayle & Wu (2013)](https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/52850/1/MPRA_paper_52850.pdf), and have similar data from two time periods:

```
df_2016 <- structure(list(YEAR = c(2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L
), MARKET = c("ATL-AUS", "ATL-AUS", "ATL-AUS", "ATL-AUS", "ATL-AUS", 
"ATL-AUS"), AIRLINE = c("WN", "UA", "DL", "AA", "F9", "WN"), 
    DIRECT = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")

  YEAR  MARKET AIRLINE DIRECT
1 2016 ATL-AUS      WN      1
2 2016 ATL-BIR      UA      0
3 2016 BIR-OGC      DL      1
4 2016 BIR-OGC      AA      0
5 2016 CFR-GHV      F9      1
6 2016 GHV-OFV      WN      0

df_2017 <- structure(list(YEAR = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L
), MARKET = c("ATL-AUS", "ATL-AUS", "ATL-AUS", "ATL-AUS", "ATL-AUS", 
"ATL-AUS"), AIRLINE = c("WN", "UA", "AA", "DL", "F9", "WN"), 
    DIRECT = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")

  YEAR  MARKET AIRLINE DIRECT
1 2017 ATL-AUS      WN      1
2 2017 ATL-BOS      UA      0
3 2017 GHV-OFV      AA      0
4 2017 ATL-AUS      DL      1
5 2017 ATL-AUS      F9      1
6 2017 ATL-AUS      WN      0
```

For a given market (in 2017), I would like to count from the 2016 data the number of airlines operating in each end point but not in the market. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with „endpoint“? Please also share what‘s your expected output.

Comment: don't understand your objective *"For a given market (in 2017), I would like to count from the 2016 data the number of airlines operating in each end point but not in the market"*, could you elaborate it and show your expected output as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if this logic fits your task:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


x <- df_2016 %>%
  separate_wider_delim(MARKET, names = c("Origin", "Destination"), delim = "-") %>% 
  summarise(Airlines = list(AIRLINE), .by = c(Origin, Destination))

df_2017 %>%
  separate_wider_delim(MARKET, names = c("Origin", "Destination"), delim = "-") %>% 
  left_join(x, join_by(Origin, Destination)) %>%
  summarise(Count = n_distinct(AIRLINE), .by =   c(YEAR, Origin, Destination))
```

```
  YEAR Origin Destination Count
1 2017    ATL         AUS     5
```

Comment: @ZéLoff I've not approved your edit yet - by itself it doesn't allow the code to run (due to the `df_2016_split` issue you noted as well) so I'd rather have TarJae amend it in line with their intentions if possible.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion earlier; it occurred while I was shortening the code. The issue should be resolved now. Also, please note that I am not currently at my desktop computer.

Comment: @TarJae: This still doesn't run. Should `x` (line 4) be renamed to `airlines_not_in_market_2016` (line 10)?

Comment: correct. Now I am back on my desktop and have a clear overview. thanks! I corrected!

Comment: I get this error: Error in `summarise()`:
! Can't supply `.by` when `.data` is a grouped data frame.

Comment: Be sure to have the acutal version of dplyr: `install.packages("dplyr")` then it should work!